# Python ast.Print "nl" argument?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

According to the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.2/library/ast.html), `ast.Print` takes an optional, boolean `nl` argument. What is it for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It marks the difference between `print 'foo'` and `print 'foo',`. The latter omits the trailing linebreak.

```
In [1]: import ast

In [2]: ast.dump(ast.parse('print "hi"'))
Out[2]: "Module(body=[Print(dest=None, values=[Str(s='hi')], nl=True)])"

In [3]: ast.dump(ast.parse('print "hi",'))
Out[3]: "Module(body=[Print(dest=None, values=[Str(s='hi')], nl=False)])"
```

Comment: Was going to ask what `nl` stood for when it dawned on me that it is `newline`.